# kendo-chart with local-data - fire event when redraw end

Tags: javascript, kendo-chart

I have kendoChart control at my project.
My chart has local data.
By kendoChart default behavior, when user click legend, it toggle to match series visibility.

I debugged at kendo-library and see that it calls function "redraw" for do it.
I need to do something after the redraw is finished.

Is there any way to do it?

```
   var chart = $('#' + obj.controlId());
        chart.kendoChart({
            title: {
                padding: 1,
                margin: 1
            },
            chartArea: {
                margin: 1,
                height: 200,
                padding: 10,
                margin: 10
            },
            plotArea: { margin: 1 },
            dataSource: {data: myChartData},
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                field: 'value',
                categoryField:'category',
                padding: 0
            }],
            legend: {
                labels: {

                    template: "#= text # #= value #"
                },
                position: 'right',
                offsetY: 20,
                offsetX: 50,
                margin: 0,
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got support from kendo-ui support-team.

His answer was to use render event.

I did it, it works well